# Defining a factory method inside an abstract class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I have an abstract class called `FyElement`:

```
abstract class FyElement {
  String get name;
  Widget get render;

  /// We need to convert the JSON to an element to render it.
  FyElement fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return ' Element: $name';
  }
}
```

The problem is in implementing `fromMap`; I want it to be a factory, not an abstract method. meaning, I want to have a blueprint for each class that can create the whole object without using the object itself. So I want my implementations look like this:

```
class SampleElement extends FyElement {
  final Something something;
  SampleElement({
    this.something,
  });

  @override
  String name = 'SampleElement';

  @override
  Widget render = const Text('SampleElement');

  @override
  factory FyElement fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    // the implementation.
  }
}
```

But when I try to use `factory` or `static` keywords inside my abstract class, I get an error. I need to be able to create the element using some inputs from a JSON file, but due to inability in using `factory`, I should have the object for creating the object:

```
SampleElement(something: something).fromMap(data);
```

which makes no sense and has no use to me. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: factory and static methods will not be inherited. And since factory defines a constructor, and abstract classes are classes without constructed instances, the factory keyword is not useful for abstract classes.

Comment: Any idea how can I solve my issue? @scrimau

Comment: For clarity: When you call `SampleElement.fromMap(...)` you want an object of type `SampleElement`, not `FyElement` ?

Comment: @RobertSandberg makes a valid point. What is it, that you want to archieve? You asked "how can i declare a factory constructor in an abstract class?", but that is not possible, so there is no way to "solve" it. When you want to construct a "normal" class, that is certainly possible, but you cannot inherit its constructor to child classes, since they may need to initiate completly different structures. So the solution would be, to define an explicit constructor for every child class. Depending on the problem, you might be able to use template types / generics for your classes, though...

Comment: `SampleElement` inherits `FyElement` and it doesn't make a difference which one is being created. But when in this case, if we're defining it as an abstract method (or whatever) we'll need it to be `FyElement`, don't you think? Or am I mistaken? @RobertSandberg

Comment: `FyElement` knows nothing about `final Something something;` So it should make a difference...

Comment: Uh, now I get it. You mean we won't be able to create an instance of an abstract class, which makes sense. In that regard, Yes, I want to return `SampleElement`. But I need it to be declared inside the abstract class (because of polymorphism). @RobertSandberg @scrimau

Comment: I thought about using dynamic type `<T>` in declaring classes but I don't think it's possible. And would you elaborate on this "So the solution would be, to define an explicit constructor for every child class."? I think I didn't get it. @scrimau

Comment: I was going to give you a couple of examples on how to go about. First is a bit wonky, and second you'd perhaps be on thin ice... But now that I write the second one it just doesn't make any sense... So I'll leave you with one way do get you as close as possible.

Comment: Thanks. The project is an app maker. Each page comprises of few elements and we should be able to create these elements from a JSON map. I want to isolate implementation of each element from another so I'm not using practices like Abstract Factory design pattern. In that case, I could create a class that generates elements based on name or something but each time I add an element, I have to modify my previous code. @RobertSandberg

Comment: When creating an instance, you have to call a specific constructor. You may treat the instance as instance of a parent class / interface, and therefore enforce some kind of masking of implementation details via your abstract class. But the constructor has to be called with a specific implementation in mind. Therefore, the alternative would be to define a specific implementation of a constructor for every child class.

Comment: If you can generalize the functionality for every json map, why use different classes in the first place? In your example, you define 2 properties (name and render), but both are set not by the fromJson method, but by specific implementations from your child class. Whats the use of the abstract class here anyway? It is entirely obsolete. Thats making it hard to understand your question.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't clearly understand what you say. Can you provide what you said as an answer? Because I don't see how is it relevant to my problem. I want to call `SampleElement.fromMap(data);` instead of `SampleElement(something: something).fromMap(data);` @scrimau

Comment: why do you want this? when you dont use data at all to initialize anything specific in your instance... If i would make a wild guess: You want to build something (a page widget?) out of that json data? then you might want to create an instance of a "Builder" but the build method itself could be just that, just a method at a builder class, that takes json data and returns something (a page widget). So, why the need for inheritance and abstract classes?

Comment: Because as mentioned in my comment above, the project is an app maker. Each page (of type `FyPage` which itself is an abstract class) comprises of one or more `FyElement` objects. I want to automate serialization process inside my `FyPage` class, meaning for a given list of JSON data (of elements), create a page from that json. What is the type of my elements inside my `FyPage`? `FyElement`. So, I want to map each item inside the list (JSON) to a FyElement. Thus, needing to call `SampleElement.fromMap(data);` instead of `SampleElement(something: something).fromMap(data);`. @scrimau

Comment: Up to the point, where you switched from FyElement to SampleElement all of a sudden. I still dont see, why the switch to abstract classes is happening. Furthermore, i dont see why you would need to create classes for these app pages/elements at all. Good old `Widget` class would at least do it for flutter terms, no? I see, why you would want to parse your json data in a class, certainly. But this would need to be done, per DTO/DAO/Request/Response object, and not per "page"/"element" object. furthermore, the direction would still be json -> elements. which could be a simple function.

Comment: It looks to me, like your stuck up on the idea, that every page/element needs to be its own "class", while trying to generalize functionality over these different classes. When this is exactly, what instances are for. Where instead of a different class for every page, you actually want to create an instance of a FyPage class. and use these generalized properties for your build process. So, basically, do you really need to use "abstract classes" and "classes", or maybe you could use "classes" and "instances" instead?

Comment: I see. I think it's better do handle my serialization in a different class. I thought what I wanted was possible in dart (as it is in PHP or python). Thanks for the input my friend. (And no, project is too extensive with lots of customizations and plugins and stuff and can't just use simple widget.) @scrimau

Comment: Well, one last input from my end: If you want to generalize functionality over different classes, without inheritance, maybe a `mixin` is what your looking for. You would still only be able to generalize an "init" method, which would still be needed to be called in an constructor. And im not really convinced, that it would be "clean" or even useful for your intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, you cannot achieve what you are after. The closest way around it is using methods. And based on my understanding of how you want to force the calls to be made, this is a wonky way:

```
abstract class FyElement<T> {
  T _fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data);
}

class SampleElement implements FyElement<SampleElement> {
  late final int something;

  SampleElement._();

  factory SampleElement.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return SampleElement._().._fromMap(data);
  }

  @override
  SampleElement _fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    something = data['something'];
    return this;
  }
}
```

Called as:

```
var foo = SampleElement.fromMap({'something': 2});
```

This way you will be forced to implement the `fromMap` method, but it cannot be called as an instance member. You will however need to remember the factory constructor and private constructor on SampleElement yourself.

Comment: I didn't know what 'wonky' means, now I know.  
Yes, this is correct, but if this is the only way to go, using Abstract Factory design pattern is a better solution IMHO. Also, using `late` keyword for class attributes won't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: TBH this was the answer to my question, but overall, I think it's better not to do this and use another class and abstract factory design pattern. Thanks for your efforts and help. Much appreciated.